# "Empty table from specified data source" error in Create ML

Tags: createml

I'm trying to train a new object detection model using the Create ML tool from Apple. I've already used RectLabel to generate annotations for all of the JPEG images in my directory of training images.

However, every time I try loading the directory in Create ML, I receive this error message:

> Empty table from specified data source

I already looked on the [Apple Developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120640) and that thread incorrectly claims the problem was solved in a previous update.

What causes this error? How can I get Create ML to accept my training data?

[image]

I'm using Create ML Version 2.0 (53.2.2) and RectLabel Version 3.04.2 (3.04.2) on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29).

Answer (score 5):

The “Empty table from specified data source” error occurs if any of the filenames contain spaces.

My solution was to rename all the files so the filenames don't contain spaces.

Comment: This was it for me, as Annotate ML exports with spaces. I edited the json file and the filenames.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that there are only images and annotations.json file in your directory of training images.

If there are any other files including .mlproj file in the folder, Create ML shows the "Empty table from specified data source" error.

When you create a new project on Create ML, specify outside the directory of training images.

Comment: Note that this includes hidden files (those beginning with a dot which can't be seen by the Finder). You may want to look for those in Terminal - `ls -la` - and then delete them using `rm .nameofhiddenfile`.

Comment: Following from the comment above, if you used a python notebook to format anything, there will also be an .ipynb_checkpoints/ directory that will need to be removed with rm -r .ipynb_checkpoints/